# Center CSS 'content' attribute in image overlay

Tags: html, css

```css
.image {
  padding: 0px;
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px !important;
  margin: 15px;
  position:relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image img {
  width:100%;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

.image:after {
  content:'x';
  font-family:Helvetica;
  font-weight:900;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  font-size:24px;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%; height:100%;
  top:0; right:0;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  opacity:0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
}

.image:hover:after {
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2013/1/11/1357921737290/Masterclass-in-HTML5-and--006.jpg" />
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/9u06fbbf/

What I want is that the 'x' that appears when you hover over the image is centered vertically.
I tried display: table-cell with vertical-align: middle, but i just can't seem to get it to work properly.

I want this to work for multiple images with different sizes and aspect ratios!

Any ideas?

Comment: [this?](http://jsfiddle.net/9u06fbbf/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/9u06fbbf/10/

removing `max-width` and `max-height`

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/9u06fbbf/13/

used `:before` for `content:"x"`

```
.image:before {
    content:'x';
    font-family:Helvetica;
    font-weight:900;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    font-size:24px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    z-index:2;
    transform:translateY(-50%);
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Hats off to ya.

Answer (score 0):

You could pad it so that it's vertically aligned.

```
.image:after {
  content:'x';
  font-family:Helvetica;
  font-weight:900;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  font-size:24px;
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  width:100%; height:100%;
  padding-top:25%; // changed from top: 0;
  right:0;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  opacity:0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: If I do that, then the overlay doesn't show at all anymore.

Comment: It happens because the top value has been removed. Add it again.

Comment: @BramVanroy - edited to include that as you suggested. Noticed that you have the same response below, have an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

working Fiddle;
updated
http://jsfiddle.net/9u06fbbf/15/

```
.image {
    padding: 0px;
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 200px !important;
    margin: 15px;
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.image img {
    width:100%;
    margin-top: 1px;
}
.image:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.image:before {
    content:'x';
    font-family:Helvetica;
    font-weight:900;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    font-size:24px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    z-index:2;
    transform:translateY(-50%);
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    opacity:0;
}
.image:hover:after, .image:hover:before {
    opacity:1;
}
```

Reference for further
[Vertical align anything with just 3 lines of CSS](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/)

Answer (score 0):

You should add **padding-top:25%;
http://jsfiddle.net/9u06fbbf/9/

```
.image:after {
  padding-top:25%;
  content:'x';
  font-family:Helvetica;
  font-weight:900;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  font-size:24px;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%; height:100%;
  top:0; right:0;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  opacity:0;    
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
}
```